Traefik always returns 404
I am trying to set up traefik for a very simple containerized application and it always returns 404 when I am trying to hit any of my app's endpoints. Inside my-service docker container I am running a Go application that listens on port 80. The problem is definitely with traefik setup and not with the app itself because it works just fine without traefik.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:

  my-service:
    container_name: my-service-backend
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.my-service.rule=Host(`my-service.docker.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.services.my-service.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.port=80
      - traefik.enable=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-${ENV}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      USER: ${DB_USER}
      PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB: ${DB_NAME}
      HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      LISTEN_PORT: ${LISTEN_PORT}
      ENV: ${ENV}
    networks:
      - backend
  
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v3.0
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker. DISABLE IN PRODUCTION
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.yaml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yaml
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend


traefik.yaml:
accessLog: {}
log: {}

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: backend

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true
  debug: true

entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"


What am I doing wrong here?
curl -GET localhost:80/ping and curl -GET my-service.docker.localhost/ping always return 404 as well as all the other endpoints. In the traefik logs I can see something like
192.168.65.1 - - [12/Jun/2024:03:51:12 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 404 19 "-" "-" 1 "my-service@docker" "http://172.18.0.3:80" 18ms

First note that you can not mix Traefik static config in traefik.yml and command:, decide for one.
It seems you want to use Docker Swarm because of the
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 1

If this is the case, then you need to use providers.swarm, which got separated from providers.docker in Traefik v3.
When using Traefik with Docker Swarm, you need to place the labels inside the deploy: section to be picked up for configuration discovery.
Finally, enable and check Traefik debug log and Traefik access log in JSON format for more details.
